# system() with evince never returns

Tags: c, system, return

I am using system() to launch evince on Linux, it works fine until I load a document and try to close it. When I try to close the document system() never returns:

My code:

```
char systemString[MAXPATHLEN];
sprintf( systemString, "%s", "evince" );

int ret = system( systemString );
if ( ret == -1 )
{
   perror( "system" );
   exit(1);
}
```

Any idea why? If not, how do I debug this, when use it in the debugger it never returns in it either. The code is rather large and some signals are blocked, but I tried some I thought this used and same error.

Thanks

Comment: When you open evince from a shell, does it return?

Comment: If you launch `evince` from a `sh` terminal do you experience the same problem? Do you get some error messages?

Comment: No, only from within the program, works from cmd line sh just fine. I ran another program that launches evince in a similar fashion and it has no problems, but its a smaller program, it's something with my code, but I don't know what it is. If its before this or this causing it.

Comment: Where does `strace` say that your program is stuck?

Comment: Here: int ret = system( systemString ); Once this runs it never returns. But that's only when I open a file in Evince, it's I open no files it returns just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found its because SIGTERM is being blocked but the program. This is a large legacy program.

Comment: Have you tried system"evince &"); ? This will cause the subshel to run evince in the background and exit to the caller even before evince exits or teminates.

Comment: Thanks, I would but I found there was a whole section of code blocking signals it should not have and it fixed the problem.

Comment: "section of code blocking signals it should not have" : syntax error.